# Specifying the frequencies when designing a filter

Tags: filters

I understand the general method of designing high pass and low pass filters with a specific number of poles and zeros. However, if given a specific sampling frequency, let's say 2.4 kHz, and asked to make

1. the peak of the high pass filter to be 1.2 kHz
   and
2. the peak in the passband region of the bandpass filter 1.2 kHz.

How would I specify these frequencies for the peak and band pass region of the filters?

Comment: um, there's a bad relationship between your sampling rate and your "peak" frequencies. How can something be a bandpass filter, if the Nyquist band is [-1.2 kHz;+1.2 kHz] and put the bassband region at +1.2 kHz? It's a high-pass filter, by definition, then.